# extract subset from macro argument

Tags: c++, boost, macros

I have a large number of variable names each of which have the following pattern,

1. ABC_00_fld1
2. ABC_01_fld1

What I would like to achieve is pass these arguments to a macro, in c++ and strip out the prefixes. Something like this:

```
#define MAKE_FLD( param )\
    some manipulation on param
```

Expected result:

```
MAKE_FLD( ABC_00_fld1 ) =>  fld1
```

I know we can achieve this via simple functions, however choice of macro is constrained on me, and I have lot of other moving pieces which will source the above function to generate more macros. I am not aware of a way to do this in c++. I have looked into stringify but I am not sure if that fits the bill. Kindly post your suggestions.

EDIT:
Reading all suggestions compels me to provide more background. To give some perspective as to the use of this macro. Consider application is generating structs using macros. So each struct is going to have a bunch of data members. Above mentioned "ABC_00_fld1" becomes the data type of the class which is defined in some other part of the application. So in the struct generated via a macro would look something like this.

```
struct macro_struct_fld1 {
    ABC_00_fld1 fld1;
};

struct macro_struct_fld2 {
    ABC_01_fld1 fld1;
};
```

This above snippet is the motivation for what I am trying to achieve. There are other ways to achieve the above as well, where in to my macro-generatedd struct instead of passing a list of data types, I can pass in a list of enums containing data type and variable name and extract that out, but then I have to hand-construct the names which I would not enjoy.

Comment: string operations aren't something macros are very good at.   There are some stack overflow questions about this - did you google?

Comment: Can your macro expand to function calls?

Comment: What do you intend to do with these shortened variable names?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Would that help? it seems like the OP wants these modifications at compile time because they are variable names.

Comment: @Ben I just realized the OP doesn't want stringified stuff.

Comment: question edited. Kindly take a look

Answer (score -1):

You can use a C preprocessor feature called Stringification (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html) to get a string version of the parameter name.

From there you can manipulate the string; something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#define MAKE_FLD(param) (std::string(#param).substr(7))

int main()
{
    int ABC_00_fld1 = 0;

    std::cout << MAKE_FLD(ABC_00_fld1) << std::endl;

    return ABC_00_fld1;
}
```

This outputs "fld1".  Code compiled and tested here: http://cpp.sh/8tkk

Comment: I'm afraid that's not really in question (though OP talks about _stringification_).

Comment: Unless I am misunderstanding something, OP wants to turn variable names into strings.  There is only one way to do that without hardcoding string literals that match up with the parameter names; thats stringification.  Also possible to not use std::string by instead incrementing the char* literal by a known number of chars: (#param + 7). This would get compile time calculated const char * with the correct value.

Comment: I think the op wants something more like `int MAKE_FLD(ABC_00_fld1) = 0; return fld1;` to work. We need clarification though.

Comment: @johnsmith now that you edited your question, it seems you might be able to generate your field names (and struct names or any other name) through concatenation instead.  You can do #define MAKE_FLD(p1, p2) (p1##p2) and use it something like this MAKE_FLD(ABC_00_, fld1) which will result in ABC_00_fld1 that is NOT a string.